# Wordpress database connection plugin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I made a kind of plugin just for the database connection it works but if i activate my plugin the page wil go a little bit down so actually my site will become ugly

```
 $servername = "xxxx";  // naam of ip van de machine ... 127.0.0.1
          $username = "xxxx";  //naam van gebruiker
          $password = "xxxx"; // wachtwoord
          $dbname = "xxxx"; //db naam
          $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
          if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
                    if (isset($_GET["code"]) )
    {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    }
    else
    {
        $code = '';
    }
    //$naam = '%DR%';

    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM docenten WHERE naam=\"$naam\"";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cadeaubon` WHERE Kortingscode like \"$code\"";

    //echo $sql; //debuggen
    echo "<BR>";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "- ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Kortingscode: " . $row["Kortingscode"]. " - Aantal personen: " . $row["AantPersonen"] . " - Naam: " . $row["Naam"] . " -  Achternaam: " . $row["Achternaam"] . " - Leeftijd: " . $row["Leeftijd"] . " - Datum: " . $row["Datum"]."<br>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

this is my code and i thought maybe it will help if the result will display at the bottom of the page but i dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you left there `<br>` from your debug echo:

```
//echo $sql; //debuggen
echo "<BR>";
```

However I don't know where in code this gets executed and how it integrates with WordPress. If the following table is shown inside content area of the page, the `<br>` shouldn't affect your site design other than pushing the table one line down.

It also seems to be a bit of overkill to create your own database connection - I would think WordPress already is connected and it would be preferable to use its own connection, unless it is a completely different database.

Comment: but do you know how i can display my result at the end of my page?

Comment: I never developed a WordPress plugin, and even if I had, you would need to be more specific. If you want it at the end of content, there's where you should initialize the plugin. If you want it in the footer, you need to make the plugin affect the footer instead of content. Quick hack would be to use fixed position through CSS, but that's not a way to go for a serious plugin design, as it will need to be written specifically for any template used.

Comment: Well it's just for my self so it is not a big problem

Comment: Then something like `<div style="position:fixed;z-index:100;bottom:0;width:100%;background:solid white;"></div>` enclosing your table could do. But it may break (design of site) when you update theme or WordPress. Also you need to make sure there's enough blank space after your footer.